# make a DLL work on MacOS

Tags: java

I have a Jar application that I use on Windows, it uses some DLL files to send and receive messages from them, so i'm trying to find a way to make it work on MacOS, I tried to run the jar first to see what will happen:

```
java -cp myApp.jar
```

It worked until the time that the app requires one of the DLLs, so I got this:

```
/Users/XXX/Java/bin/myDLL.dll: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x4D 0x5A 0x90 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

I found some tips to use Wine, but I don't have any idea how to convert those DLLs so the app can use them on MacOS.

Note: The Jar app has many files like DLLs, GIFs, and INI files that are needed to work.

Comment: You can't. You need to recompile the sources of those libraries for OSX.

Comment: I’m not the owner, isn’t there a way to compile the whole files to a single app that plays the Jar in a Windows environment?

Comment: You can't compile anything without the source code.

Comment: Even with Wine?

Comment: You could run them with Windows emulation, yes, but not recompile them. DLLs are binaries, not source code.

Comment: As mentioned below, my goal is to get the app out of the Emulators. Thank you for your notes.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's why I said you can't :)

Comment: Have you asked the project owners if the would consider a macOS version?

Comment: Unfortunately the app project is dead since 2005, and we don't have an alternative app that does exactly like it.

Answer (score 2):

Java itself is cross-platform, but native code such as your DLL is not.  Under no circumstances can you expect to load a Windows DLL directly into your OS X JVM and run anything within.  You could, however, run your code on OS X in a *Windows* JVM via a Windows emulation layer such as [Crossover Mac](https://www.codeweavers.com/products/crossover-mac) or [Parallels Desktop](https://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/).  Note that these are both commercial products, however, as are most others in this category, and also that OS emulation imposes a performance cost.

Comment: Thanks, my whole idea of this question is to get my app out of Parallels! I hate those VMs. I use the app most of the time and im forced to use the VM that eats the memory.

Comment: Or possible wine as an emulation layer?  Or windows within a virtualbox :)